# Motion sensors - detectable when using mobile network?

Tags: mobile, detection

Motion sensors are a good way to be informed of any activity at our house. Many modern motion sensors have the possibility to notify the user using an internet connection using Wi-Fi or even mobile data network by inserting a SIM card (where no wifi exists).

This is a good way to secure our home. But from another perspective, an abuser can use this device to get information about someone also.

Let's say we have a scenario in which we suspect that someone put such device to our home. We have the option to find that device physically by searching for it around the house, which can take hours of searching.

Is such a device possible to locate using any method or device which could locate it?

Comment: Let's back up a bit. The fact that the device is a motion sensor does not affect the question at all because they are (often) passive. Because the unauthorised device is not likely to have access to your wifi, your question becomes, "how can we detect devices that are transitting via the cell network?"

Comment: If the device does have access to your wifi, then the solution is trivial: log into the admin panel of the AP and see what's connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## If the device uses cellular

You can use devices like [this](https://www.shoghicom.com/gsm-direction-finder.php) or [these](https://www.eyetek.co.uk/bug-hunters) to find the device.

## If the device uses WiFi

Some enterprise AP configuration tools can locate a device in a building, so this could be used to detect the bug

## If the device uses other RF

You would need to use a receiver or SDR to detect and move towards the strongest signal. These devices can be used to detect the other options too, but the more specialised devices may get better results.

---

## Issues

These answers rely on the device transmitting when you are looking for it. If it only pulses quickly, or batches up data together, then it will be harder to find.

Comment: A great and clear answer explaining alot of things. Thank you. I honestly did not know such detectors actually exist.